# ¿Como restringir el acceso a una web por un dia en php?

Tags: php, web

le explico mi caso, tengo una web de encuestas y en donde el usuario cuando lo complete y envié sus respuesta, este ya no pueda enviar ó ingresar nuevamente la encuesta y que le muestre otra pantalla que intente luego (pero en si podrá verlo de nuevo dentro de 24horas o x horas)
PD: Estoy usando php en el back

Comment: Agrega aquello que hayas intentado así como dudas puntuales por favor, de otro modo la pregunta terminará cerrada por tener problemas de formato

Comment: ¿Guardas algún tipo de identificador del usuario? No se, el footprint del navegador, un id, etc. Si tienes eso, es trivial... lo pones en la base de datos con el último acceso y ya

Comment: Y no tienes que identificar personalmente a los usuarios, diles que te creen una cuenta temporal y ya, por ahí puede ser